# Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type database

Tags: web-services, enterprise-library

This issue relates to  web service application that uses Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.

When I test one of the APIs and get to DAL portion of the code I get an error at this point:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration;
....
Database oDatabase = null;
....
oDatabase = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>();
```

web.config looks like:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</configSections>
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="DefaultConnectionString">
    <providerMappings>
          <add databaseType="EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet.OracleDatabase, EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
    </providerMappings>
</dataConfiguration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.2.3.4)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID = MySID)));User Id=some_id;Password=some_pwd;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The exception is:

Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type Database, key \"\"

and inner exception shows:

Resolution of the dependency failed,

type = "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database", name = "(none)".

Exception occurred while: while resolving.

Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type Database cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.

At the time of the exception, the container was:\r\n\r\n  Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database,(none)

I searched for this issue and tried suggestions ranging from checking DLL versions to making various modifications to web.config but still getting errors. I think they key is not in the error message itself but the inner exception.

I'd appreciate it if someone has had the same issue can tell me what the resolution was or a guru who can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have been caused by using incorrect version of Oracle client. I had 12c client, both 32 and 64 bits but what I needed was 11g. After installing 11g client, I no longer got the error.